# how to remove `<h2 class='title'>Some text</h2>` using sed?

Tags: sed

to remove `text1`, I simply use:

```
find mydirectory -type f -exec sed -i 's/text1//ig' {} +
```

but how to remove `<h2 class='title'>Some text</h2>`?

I cannot simply remove using below code. it not works:

```
find mydirectory -type f -exec sed -i 's/<h2 class='title'>Some text</h2>//ig' {} +
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to escape the special characters

```
find mydirectory -type f -exec sed -i 's/<h2 class=\'title\'>Some text<\/h2>//ig' {} +
```